# Group by using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which has several records of the details of products and medications which is purchased by each customer.

[image]

My requirement is as below:

1. I need to extract a around 5 fields in that.
2. I need to group them by a combination of two fields (products and medication in my case)
3. I need to get the number of customers who bought these combination.
4. I need to get the total tonnes of these combination.

I want to create a new list with this information.

I don't have an idea how to go with it. I have done something like below:

```
var k = lstOutWeigh.GroupBy(p => new { prod = p.Product, med = p.Medication });
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far, so we can correct it. If you haven't gotten any code so far, please tell us why.

Comment: @JakubKonecki you're right, my comment wasn't really complete. I have deleted it. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the examples below:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea

You're looking for something along the lines of:

```
from t in Transactions
group t by new { t.Product, t.Medication } into g
select new 
{ 
    TotalWeight = g.Sum(x => x.NettWeight),
    Count = g.Count()
}
```

Comment: Hi Jakub, thanks for your answer. If I want to get the count of the records with this combination, what shall I do? Thanks in adcvance